# Persisting a multiple level XML/JSON Data into a Table

Tags: xml, rest, spring-boot, jpa

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm learning about JPA and REST.

I'm trying to setup a REST service that receive a POST request with a XML and write into a single table, but I'm stucked with "sub-levels" into the XML.

This is the "normal" XML that my service receive(this actually works):

```
<somexml>
   <xmlid>1</xmlid>
   <xmldesc>Test</xmltest>
   <xmlclassif>04<xmlclassif>
   <xmlbar>123456789</xmlbar>
   <xmlsize>003</xmlsize>
   <xmlres>1</xmlres>
</somexml>
```

Here is the "Special" case that I'm stucked:

```
<somexml>
   <xmlid>01</xmlid>
   <xmldesc>Test</xmltest>
   <xmlclassif>04<xmlclassif>
   <xmlbars>
      <xmlbarid>01</xmlbarid>
      <xmlbar>00000000001</xmlbar>
   </xmlbar>
   <xmlbars>
      <xmlbarid>01</xmlbarid>
      <xmlbar>00000000002</xmlbar>
   </xmlbar>
   <xmlbars>
      <xmlbarid>01</xmlbarid>
      <xmlbar>00000000003</xmlbar>
   </xmlbar>
   <xmlbars>
      <xmlbarid>01</xmlbarid>
      <xmlbar>00000000004</xmlbar>
   </xmlbar>
   <xmlsize>003</xmlsize>
   <xmlres>1</xmlres>
</somexml>
```

If I receive one "xmlbar" my service works as expected, but I d'ont know how to "read" the multiples "xmlbars" and write them, the example have 4 "xmlbars", but could be a lot more.

I need the follow data on the table from the above example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Dyn.png

Here is my entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "somexml")
@XmlRootElement
public class Somexml{
    private Long xmlid;
    private Long xmldesc;
    private Long xmlclassif;
    private Long xmlbar;
    private Long xmlsize;
    private Long xmlres;


    public Somexml(Long xmlid, Long xmldesc, Long xmlclassif, Long xmlbar, Long xmlsize, Long xmlres) {
        super();
    }

    public Somexml() {
        super();
        this.xmlid = xmlid;
        this.xmldesc = xmldesc;
        this.xmlclassif = xmlclassif;
        this.xmlbar = xmlbar;
        this.xmlsize = xmlsize;
        this.xmlres= xmlres;

    }

... getters and setters
```

Repository

```java
@Repository
public interface XmlRepository extends JpaRepository<Xml, Long>{

}
```

...and here is the call from controller

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/xml")
    public Xml createXml(@RequestBody Xml xml) {
        Xml savedXml = xmlRepository.save(xml);

        return xml;
    }
```

I dont know if is the best way to do this, but is the way that I learned/know, if you have a better way, using Spring boot, I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

A valid alternative would be to create your own type and then a converter for it. For example, let's say you want to persist a JSON.
First you define your own 'type' for it:

```
public class Json extends HashMap<String, String> {}
```

Then you create your own converter for your new type by implementing AttributeConverter. Or you could even define an abstract class that implements the interface and acts as basic converter and then extend that whenever you need a new converter for another type. Anyway, the basic idea would be:

```
@Converter (autoApply = true)
public class JsonConverter implements AttributeConverter<Json, String> { 
   @Override
   public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Json json) {
       // ...
   }

   @Override
   public Color convertToEntityAttribute(String colorString) {
       // ...
   }
}
```

Now you can use it in your entities like so:

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Convert(converter = JsonConverter.class)
    private Json myJsonInformation;
}
```

[Here](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters) you can read more about AttributeConverter.

Hope this helps!